# Java Thread Safety of Initialized Objects

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

Consider the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private MyObject obj;

    public MyClass()
    {
        obj = new MyObject();
    }

    public void methodCalledByOtherThreads()
    {
        obj.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Since obj was created on one thread and accessed from another, could obj be null when methodCalledByOtherThread is called?  If so, would declaring obj as volatile be the best way to fix this issue?  Would declaring obj as final make any difference?

Edit:
For clarity, I think my main question is:
Can other threads see that obj has been initialized by some main thread or could obj be stale (null)?

Comment: So are you asking whether it would be possible for another thread to get a reference to an object of class `MyClass` _before its constructor is complete_?  Good question!  Try it out, though.  Try writing code on the other thread. :)

Comment: With the current code you have, no, since a `this` reference does not escape the constructor.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you should probably make that an answer rather than a comment.  I think the question was pretty good and deserving of an answer that could be accepted.  Just a thought, you might disagree.....

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457109/java-concurrency-is-final-field-initialized-in-constructor-thread-safe

Comment: @RayToal Not quite.  I am fairly certain this is not possible.  I am wondering whether methodCalledByOtherThreads might read a stale value of obj.

Comment: Then even better.  But by state value do you mean a field?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am not sure what you mean by "this reference does not escape the constructor"  Could you clarify or provide an example.  Thanks

Comment: @RayToal Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the `methodCalledByOtherThreads` to be called by another thread and cause problems, that thread would have to get a reference to a `MyClass` object whose `obj` field is not initialized, ie. where the constructor has not yet returned.

This would be possible if you leaked the `this` reference from the constructor. For example

```
public MyClass()
{
    SomeClass.leak(this); 
    obj = new MyObject();
}
```

If the `SomeClass.leak()` method starts a separate thread that calls `methodCalledByOtherThreads()` on the `this` reference, then you would have problems, but this is true regardless of the `volatile`.

Since you don't have what I'm describing above, your code is fine.

Comment: Can you explain the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728710/coding-a-proof-for-potential-concurrency-issue and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457109/java-concurrency-is-final-field-initialized-in-constructor-thread-safe

They seem to say that the code is not fine.

Thanks

Comment: @Xor You're better off asking the people that answered them respectively.

Comment: Maybe I worded that wrong.  You don't need to explain others' answers.  Anyway, that second link is posted seems to contradict your answer: it says that the value assigned in the constructor is not necessarily the one threads that call methodCalledByOtherThreads() sees.

Comment: @Xor In your current code, `methodCalledByOtherThreads` can only be called by another thread after the constructor is done. At that point, the other `Thread` will see it exactly as it is. In the question itself, see the quote `If an object is properly constructed (which means that references to it do not escape during construction)`

Answer (score 4):

It depends on whether the reference is published "unsafely". A reference is "published" by being written to a shared variable; another thread reads the variable to get the reference. If there is no relationship of `happens-before(write, read)`, the publication is called unsafe. An example of unsafe publication is through a non-volatile static field.

@chrylis 's interpretation of "unsafe publication" is not accurate. Leaking `this` before constructor exit is orthogonal to the concept of unsafe publication.

Through unsafe publication, another thread may observe the object in an uncertain state (hence the name); in your case, field `obj` may appear to be null to another thread. Unless, `obj` is `final`, then it cannot appear to be null even if the host object is published unsafely.

This is all too technical and it requires further readings to understand. The good news is, you don't need to master "unsafe publication", because it is a discouraged practice anyway. The best practice is simply: never do unsafe publication; *i.e.* never do data race; *i.e.* always read/write shared data through proper synchronization, by using `synchronized, volatile` or `java.util.concurrent`.

If we always avoid unsafe publication, do we still *need* `final` fields? The answer is no. Then why are some objects (e.g. `String`) designed to be "thread safe immutable" by using final fields? Because it's assumed that they can be used in malicious code that tries to create uncertain state through deliberate unsafe publication. I think this is an overblown concern. It doesn't make much sense in server environments - if an application embeds malicious code, the server is compromised, period. It probably makes a bit of sense in Applet environment where JVM runs untrusted codes from unknown sources - even then, this is an improbable attack vector; there's no precedence of this kind of attack; there are a lot of other more easily exploitable security holes, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

This code is fine because the reference to the instance of `MyClass` can't be visible to any other threads before the constructor returns.

Specifically, the [happens-before relation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) requires that the visible effects of actions occur in the same order as they're listed in the program code, so that in the thread where the `MyClass` is constructed, `obj` must be definitely assigned before the constructor returns, and the instantiating thread goes directly from the state of not having a reference to the `MyClass` object to having a reference to a fully-constructed `MyClass` object.

That thread can then pass a reference to that object to another thread, but all of the construction will have transitively happened-before the second thread can call any methods on it. This might happen through the constructing thread's launching the second thread, a `synchronized` method, a `volatile` field, or the other concurrency mechanisms, but all of them will ensure that all of the actions that took place in the instantiating thread are finished before the memory barrier is passed.

Note that if a reference to `this` gets passed out of the class inside the constructor somewhere, that reference might go floating around and get used before the constructor is finished. That's what's known as *unsafe publishing* of the object, but code such as yours that doesn't call non-`final` methods from the constructor (or directly pass out references to `this`) is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your other thread **could** see a null object. A volatile object could possibly help, but an explicit lock mechanism (or a Builder) would likely be a better solution.

Have a look at [Java Concurrency in Practice - Sample 14.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528572/java-concurrency-in-practice-sample-14-12)

Comment: I believe this answer is correct, but could you explain why an explicit lock or Builder would be better.  Declaring obj as volatile of final seems much simpler, but just as effective.

Comment: A builder surely would not leave the reference to the object back before it was ready (and make that variable final!).

Comment: Volatile is not what you want (you don't want the null pointer right?) and it's suprisingly slow nowadays. Avoid at all costs. Final is better, but wont protect you if another thread tries to read the variable.

Comment: In this particular case, Sotirios is correct, though. A pointer cannot slip out before the object is done.

Comment: No, another thread can't see it. No reference to the `MyClass` object exists before the constructor returns, and `obj` is definitely assigned at that point. There's no way for another thread to get a reference to the `MyClass` until that happens.

Answer (score 1):

This class (if taken as is) is NOT thread safe. In two words: there is reordering of instructions in java ([Instruction reordering & happens-before relationship in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213443/instruction-reordering-happens-before-relationship-in-java)) and when in your code you're instantiating MyClass, under some circumstances you may get following set of instructions:

- Allocate memory for new instance of MyClass;
- Return link to this block of memory;
- Link to this not fully initialized MyClass is available for other threads, they can call "methodCalledByOtherThreads()" and get NullPointerException;
- Initialize internals of MyClass.

In order to prevent this and make your MyClass really thread safe - you either have to add "final" or "volatile" to the "obj" field. In this case Java's memory model (starting from Java 5 on) will guarantee that during initialization of MyClass, reference to alocated for it block of memory will be returned only when all internals are initialized.

For more details I would strictly recommend you to read nice book "Java Concurrency in Practice". Exactly your case is described on the pages 50-51 (section 3.5.1). I would even say - you just can write correct multithreaded code without reading that book! :)

Answer (score 0):

The originally picked answer by @Sotirios Delimanolis is wrong. @ZhongYu 's answer is correct.

There is the visibility issue of the concern here. So if MyClass is published unsafely, anything could happen.

Someone in the comment asked for evidence - one can check Listing 3.15 in the book *Java Concurrency in Practice*:

```
public class Holder { 
    private int n;
    
    // Initialize in thread A
    public Holder(int n) { this.n = n; }
    
    // Called in thread B
    public void assertSanity() { 
        if (n != n) throw new AssertionError("This statement is false."); 
    }

}
```

Someone comes up an example to verify this piece of code:

[coding a proof for potential concurrency issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728710/coding-a-proof-for-potential-concurrency-issue)

As to the specific example of this post:

```
public class MyClass{
    private MyObject obj;
    
    // Initialize in thread A
    public MyClass(){
        obj = new MyObject();
    }
    
    // Called in thread B
    public void methodCalledByOtherThreads(){
        obj.doStuff();
    }
}
```

If MyClass is initialized in Thread A, there is no guarantee that thread B will see this initialization (because the change might stay in the cache of the CPU that Thread A runs on and has not propagated into main memory).

Just as @ZhongYu has pointed out, because the write and read happens at 2 independent threads, so there is no `happens-before(write, read)` relation.

To fix this, as the original author has mentioned, we can declare private MyObject obj as volatile, which will ensure that the reference itself will be visible to other threads in timely manner
(https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-multi-threading/volatile-ref-object.html) .

Comment: If you want to discuss other answers, please add a comment instead of posting a new answer. Furthermore, please add evidence.